# jQuery UI tabs show/hide images based on active tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the jQuery UI tabs widget and I am trying to show/hide images based on the active widget.

I have a two column layout; left column has the tabs widget with three tabs, right column has the image(s); the image in the right column should swap depending on the active tab. Looking at the api and other posts why wouldn't my code work? How would I do it?

```
jQuery(function($) {
    //turn content into tabs
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

    var active2 = $( "#tabs-2" ).tabs( "option", "active" );

    if (active2) {
        $(".gala-img1").show();
        $(".gala-img2").hide();
        $(".gala-img3").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in your JS :

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
  activate: function (event, ui) {
    if (ui.newHeader[0]) {
      $(".gala-img" + $(ui.newHeader[0]).attr('data-imgid')).show();
    }
  },
  beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
    if (ui.oldHeader[0]) {
      $(".gala-img" + $(ui.oldHeader[0]).attr('data-imgid')).hide();
    }
  }
});
```

And put in your tabs-headers the data-imgid of the image you want, like this :

```
<li data-imgid="X">....</li>
```